# How to define a function's argument type as one of the keys (or properties) of an interface

Tags: typescript, typing

#### Given any interface, is there a way to say that a variable's type is one of the keys in that interface?

Suppose you have this interface:

```
interface IExample {
  a: string;
  b: {
    b1: string;
    b2: string | number | boolean;
  };
}
```

And you have a function like:

```
const foo = (arg) => {
  //function's logic 
}
```

Now I want to type `arg` as being `b` from `IExample`, something like:

```
const foo = (arg: IExample.b): void => {  // this generates an error
  //function's logic 
}
```

---

To be clear, the function's argument should be:

```
{
  b1: string;
  b2: string | number | boolean;
}
```

and I didn't want to have to write another interface just for that.

I couldn't find a way by myself, neither figure it out by reading the typescript docs. This is my last hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `[]` to index types. [Some documentation on this is here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)

```
function foo(arg: IExample['b']): void {
  //function's logic 
}

foo({ b1: 'abc', b2: true })
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEAecC2AHAGxQG8AoZZOALmQGcwpQBzAbnOQCMayKKOBGGvUYhW7PgCYhDZsgA+yEAFccHaPM4B7TUTgg2FAL5tDpUjCUgEYYJpDIY2gBRwoTGhmz4iAbQDkHH4AugCUNABumsAAJsg8yAD0CRZWNnZ+tMgEmkzACMikpubOxJyCyH5wHAh+ADScUsgMSiiGIUA)